# How to pass a vector to main function in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv with c++ and marking the points on an image. I want to return these points in my `main` function. I am using the function to mark points.

```
int n=4;
int TOTAL_POINTS=n;
Point pt;
vector<Point> capturePoint = vector<Point>();

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    //Mat& image= *(Mat*) param;

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
        pt.x = x;
        pt.y = y;
        cout << "Point" << TOTAL_POINTS + 1 - n << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
        capturePoint.push_back(pt);
        n--;
        //circle(mouseDetector::workingMat,pt,2,Scalar(0,0,255), 5);
        if(n==0){
           cvDestroyAllWindows();
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this from `main` as

```
setMouseCallback("Display window", CallBackFunc, (void*)&FrameMat);
```

How can I get the `capturePoint` vector values in my `main` function?

Comment: Since they're global, you just access them?

Comment: but it is showing the null value like no values is passed to this vector.

Comment: Guess you don't wait for mouse click event in your main function than. Why do you need it in your main function? Can't you add code which uses that vector to callback function?

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution. I have declared it globally then its values are also available in main.